# Rust: Benching built-in sort from Slice vs compiled sort code gives x16 difference?

Tags: rust

I was looking to run some benchmarks on sort algorithms written in Rust (benchmarking is using Criterion and cargo bench). When I compared the compiled versions vs the built-in sort(), I saw an order of magnitude difference in speed.

My question is: how is the "out-of-the-box" sort on slices SO much faster than its exact same code compiled as a library.

To try and compare apples-with-apples, I took the quicksort algorithm from the Rust source code (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/stable/src/libcore/slice/sort.rs). When I compared this directly to the sort() function provided out-of-the-box, I noticed a x16 difference in speed. I also tried playing around with optimisation settings in Cargo.toml, but these didn't make much difference.

My set-up for the test is the following:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate criterion;
extern crate sort_test;
extern crate rand;

use criterion::Criterion;
use criterion::BenchmarkId;
use rand::prelude::*;

use sort_test::rust_libcore::{heapsort, quicksort};

pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
  let mut group = c.benchmark_group("sort");

  let mut rng = thread_rng();

  for j in 0..10 {
  let mut arr_A: [u8; 160] = [0; 160];
  let mut arr_B: [u8; 160] = [0; 160];
  for i in 0..arr_A.len() {
    let mut e: u8 = rng.gen();
    loop {
      let mut is_unique = true;
      for j in 0..i {
        if arr_A[j] == e {
          e = rng.gen();
          is_unique = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if is_unique {
        break;
      }
    }
    arr_A[i] = e;
    arr_B[i] = e;
  }

  group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("rust-quicksort", j), &j, |b, j| b.iter(|| quicksort(&mut arr_A, &mut u8::lt)));
  group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("rust-heapsort", j), &j, |b, j| b.iter(|| heapsort(&mut arr_A, &mut u8::lt)));
  group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("built-in-unstable", j), &j, |b, j| b.iter(|| arr_C.sort_unstable()));
  group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("built-in-stable", j), &j, |b, j| b.iter(|| arr_C.sort()));
}
```

To summarise, even when comparing (what I understand to be) the actual Rust sort code with the built-in equivalent, I see x16 difference in speed. Why is this? I know benchmarking can be a subtle art, and maybe my benchmark is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I figured out my mistake.

Each iteration of the benchmark, I'm passing the same array into the sort function. First iteration, the sort actually does its job, but the built-in sort function has a quick-exit if the array is already sorted (so for 99 of the 100 iterations, the built-in is just quitting early). The code I copied was just the quicksort/heapsort, without the quick-exit check. The other sort algorithms I was testing, also did not have a quick-exit.